# Why does this map code give a null pointer exception?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); // line 22
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(25.4607640, 78.6432520)).title("Gaurav Joshi"));

    }
}
```

Here is basic code which I am trying to implement on Android Studio but it shows Null pointer exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.hp.g_1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
```

Comment: Please add the exception's stack trace

Comment: Probably will be your googleMap variable. I don't see it initialized anywhere.

Comment: @Fustigador `googleMap` is method's argument

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.hp.g_1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)

Comment: Are you sure R.id.googleMap is the right id?

Comment: Yes, but the googleMap you receive as the argument is not "linked" to YOUR map in your layout.

Comment: @xcesco Yes its the same

Comment: Please add the `activity_main` sources in the question too

Answer (score 2):

Please check that you define MapFragment in the layout file `activity_main.xml`. It looks like FragmentManager cannot find a map fragment and throws NPE here: `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);` because mapFragment is null

Comment: <MapFragment
        android:id="@+id/googleMap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
         />

Comment: that 's what main.xml contains

Comment: @GauravJoshi it looks very strange. Try to use this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map to add map in your app

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your problem would be declare your googleMap variable up in the class, and then, inside onMapReady:

```
this.googleMap=googleMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that "googleMap" id should be the id of the fragment container, not the fragment itself.